# Pushing defined variable into javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am using express.js and the cookie-parser middleware. I am trying to use a function to push the cookie name and the cookie value into an array.

I want the array to end up looking like the following:

```
loop = [{cookie1: value1}, {cookie2: value2}];
```

But for some reason when I push the key and the value into the array, the key is just being assigned as a string called key, instead of the actual value set in the function. So my array ends up looking like the following:

```
loop = [{key: value1}, {key: value2}];
```

I define the variable 'key' inside the function, and if I console log it inside the function it is set to the right value (i.e cookie1), but for some reason when I try to push it into the array, it just pushes in 'key' instead of the actual variable.

Below is the full function, any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
var loop = [];
cookie_objects(req.cookies);

function cookie_objects( cookies ) {
    for (var cookie in cookies) {
        if ( cookie != 'seen_cookie_message' && cookie != '_ga' ) {
            var key = cookie;
            var value = cookies[cookie];

            loop.push({key : value});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the blank object beforehand - then assign the key via bracket notation:

```
var obj = {};
obj[key] = value;
loop.push(obj);
```

Comment: Amazing! solved in literally under a minute haha... Thanks so much! As soon as it will let me accept this answer I will do so.